# Is it possible to navigate through the Storage Access Framework without the GUI?

Tags: java, android, filestream, storage-access-framework

I am currently developing a  background service that installs files from a thumb drive. Is there a way to access the thumb drive through the storage access framework, without having to go through the GUI? I couldn't apply file streaming methods, as I am denied access, as a non-root user.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.